# Get docker preferences using docker-py

Tags: python, macos, docker, dockerpy

I am trying to read the configs (preferences) set manually using docker preferences on mac from [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) python module.

I see that these preferences are stored in ~/.docker/config.json but I don't seem to find a way to access them using docker client.

I am trying to access the preference, "Securely store Docker logins in macOS keychain" particularly.

I see that we can set the config file using

docker --config

but, there is no getter for this config file?

I can see 'credsStore' property in the docker config.json but,
when I try [client.configs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configs.html) I get an empty list.

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
client.configs.list()
```

I would expect to see the value of that particular config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access client configuration information (`~/docker/config.json`) via the Docker API.  The information in that file effects the behavior of the client but it is not part of the API.

The `configs` method in the API is for accessing *container* configuration data in Docker Swarm (see "[Store configuration data using Docker Configs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/)").

You can find the complete Docker API reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/).